# Correlation between number of good flags and number of available flags?

Tags: discussion, flags

Is there any correlation between the number of good flags one has and the number of available spam and number of general flags that the user has available to them?

Here's an example:
We had a flood of spam today on Ask Ubuntu.  On Ask Ubuntu, I flagged a TON of them as spam, and as my "good flags" count increased the number of available flags I could use for flagging questions/answers increased every so often.  My question is whether that's just a coincidence, or whether there's an actual correlation between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [flag privelege in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts).

In the "How many flags do I have?" section (at the bottom), it is said:

```
- You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly.
```

**ADDITIONAL**: You should also see what @Bart has [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172209/correlation-between-number-of-good-flags-and-number-of-available-flags/172210#comment510656_172210).

Comment: That answers the question of whether the two are related.  :)  This'll be marked as accepted when the system allows it.

Comment: @TheLordofTime I don't know yet how flags are "processed" (rep not yet there! :) ). Anyway, I am fond of reading these dusty corners of SO, so, there it is.

Comment: The last line is not entirely correct. You don't get a bonus flag for each good flag. A flag weight is maintained (which used to be visible in your profile), and based on this weight extra flags are awarded or flags are taken away. There is not a 1 on 1 relationship between good flags and extra flags.

Comment: @Bart Could/Should I add/use your statement to the answer? You're the one who knows more on this. :)

Comment: I'd say your edit suffices.