# Add tooltip or link to "Inform moderator flags remaining" in Flagging dialog

Tags: feature-request, flags

When I opened a flag window, I've seen a message "11 Inform moderator flag remaining".

There is no hint, how this number is calculated, when it reduced, increased or reset.
I had to search in meta to find in [Correlation between number of good flags and number of available flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172209/correlation-between-number-of-good-flags-and-number-of-available-flags) a reference to https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts.

It will be good, if the info from "How many flags do I have?" will be shown as a tooltip or in popup, when clicking on the number of flags remaining.
Additionally the link to https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts will be useful on Flagging dialog