# Clicking "flags remaining" should link to a user's flag history page

Tags: feature-request, flags, user-interface, flag-history

On the screen for flagging posts, there's a small bit of text for "flags remaining".

[image: Screen for flagging posts]

My small suggestion would be to have the "flags remaining" text link directly to the current user's flag history page when clicked on. That way they can easily see their currently pending flags.

([Unfortunately it's not currently possible for me to hyperlink to your flag history page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248109/351462), so here's a screenshot for reference)

[image: Flag history page]

Comment: I might be nitpicking, but why do we need to see your current flag history to understand what your asking about? I feel this sort of thing should be kept private between you and the moderator staff.

Comment: Great idea, though. I sometimes want to look at this screen, myself, and have to try and remember where it is. It may also be helpful for users that have their flags declined, as this warning only seems to appear after multiple declines in a short period; the warning links you to this page, but it feels like an attempt to inform the user *post-mortem* to the fact.

Comment: @Gnemlock Not everyone may know what the flag history page looks like. I couldn't find a generic image of the flag history, and as mentioned in the post, [https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248109/351462). If someone could find a more generic page for flag history, I'd be happy to substitute it into my post.

Comment: [Related request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176186/add-tooltip-or-link-to-inform-moderator-flags-remaining-in-flagging-dialog), asking for a different link in there.